# logout.php does not redirect to intended page on server but works on localhost

Tags: php

I am trying to to understand why a simple logout.php script works on localhost but not on live server. Thanks in advance for any help.

here is the entire logout.php file

```
<?php//Start the session
session_start();

//Terminate the session
session_unset();
//Redirect users to login page
header('Location:  http://www.somewebsite.com/login');
exit(); 


?>
```

Comment: Are you on a shared host for the live server? Could be that the provider is restricting some PHP functions... **BTW:** Try adding `session_destroy();` after `session_unset();`. Read more about this [here](http://php.net/manual/de/function.session-unset.php#54731).

Comment: Try to remove second space after "Location:  "

Comment: You should enable error reporting so you can at least be notified if there is something hindering your efforts. For testing purposes, put **error_reporting(E_ALL);** at the top of that page and try again.

Comment: I spoke with host provider, they are looking into. I thought to also post the issue here in case someone has seen this before.

Comment: Ok, also have a look at [**this**](http://php.net/manual/de/function.session-unset.php#107089).

Comment: Rottingham thank you for your input.  Here is what I got when I added the suggested code "error_reporting(E_ALL);"

Comment: Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /homepages/36/d451465821/htdocs/logout.php:2) in /homepages/36/d451465821/htdocs/logout.php on line 5

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /homepages/36/d451465821/htdocs/logout.php:2) in /homepages/36/d451465821/htdocs/logout.php on line 10

Comment: Thanks Markus!  I added session_destroy(); but no change.  I am looking at the link you provid.  Thanks again!

Comment: It might be that your PHP script is generating an error before you execute `header()` or you have a space, tab or newline before opening the `<?php` tag. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9992171/1806348

Comment: @JochemKuijpers Seeing as `session_start()` is on line 5, I'd say they have 3 lines of non-php code

Comment: Jockem,  Thank you very much!  That seemed to solve the problem.  I removed a newline before <?php and it worked!!! Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @user3001162 Glad I could help, I've posted it as an answer to your question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comments, you had a newline in front of your `<?php` tag which caused output headers to be sent.

Resolve by removing the newline (or space, or tab, etc.)